# How can I pass props after fetching from database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-props

I am using `Firebase` as backend and the schema is as following

```
const sample_data = {
  Name: "",
  Address: "",
  Contact_no: "",
  Email: "",
  img_url: ""
}
```

First of all I am fetching with `async`function like this

`FetchList.js`

```
let dummy = {}

async function getItems(){
    const response = await fetch('realtime__database__of__firebase__url');
    
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Something went wrong");
      }
  
      dummy = await response.json();
}
getItems();
export default dummy;
```

then I'm passing the retrieved data to my **card** component like this.

`ListHospital.js`

```
import Card from "../UI/Card";
import dummy from "./FetchList";


const ListHospitals = () => {
    return <Card>
        {dummy}
    </Card>
}

export default ListHospitals;
```

Finally I want to access all data that I passed as props in my `CARD` component, but when I `console.log` here the output is `undefined` and when I  `console.log` after fetching the data it gives suitable output. **The problem I'm getting is the FetchList component is being exported before fetching the data.**

`Card.js`

```
import classes from "./Card.module.css";


const Card = (props) => {

    let url = props.children.img;
    console.log(url);
    return <div>
                <img src={props.children.img} alt={props.children.Name}></img>

                <h1 >{props.children.Name}</h1>
                <p>{props.children.Address}</p>
                <h3 >Contact</h3>
                <p>{props.children.Email}</p>
                <p>{props.children.Contact_no}</p>

</div>
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: Try changing `getItems();` to `await getItems();` in `FetchList.js`, does that work?

Comment: Nopes, it'll definitely throw an error because `getItems()` is being called outside of `async` function. So **await** will not work

Comment: `FetchList` isn't a React component. You should be doing the data fetching from a React component lifecycle method or `useEffect` hook when the component mounts (*or as needed on-demand*).

Comment: I tried `useEffect` still can't reach to desirable solution :( Can you put your answer :)

Comment: Export the `getItems` function

Create a State in `ListHospitals` component > 
Create another `async function` in `ListHospitals` component to invoke your `getItem` function and set it to the state. Call the new function in a `useEffect`.
Don't pass an object as `children`  via props. Pass it with another prop name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FetchList` isn't a React component. You should be doing the data fetching from a React component lifecycle method or `useEffect` hook when the component mounts (*or as needed on-demand*).

Export the `getItems` function:

```
async function getItems(){
  const response = await fetch('realtime__database__of__firebase__url');
    
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Something went wrong");
  }
  
  return response.json();
}

export default getItems;
```

Load when the component mounts. Pass the `data` as a prop to `Card` instead of as `children`.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Card from "../UI/Card";
import getItems from "./FetchList";

const ListHospitals = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    getItems()
      .then(data => setData(data))
      .catch(error => {
        // fetch can return rejected Promise, maybe handle it?
      });
  }, []);

  return <Card data={data} />;
}
```

Card - access the `data` prop.

```
const Card = ({ data }) => {
  const url = data.img;
  console.log(url);

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={data.img} alt={data.Name} />
      <h1 >{data.Name}</h1>
      <p>{data.Address}</p>
      <h3>Contact</h3>
      <p>{data.Email}</p>
      <p>{data.Contact_no}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```